# Advice for local database deployment for a Windows Application

Tags: mysql, sql, database, windows, local

I'm currently developping a Windows C# application. For development and testing purposes, I'm using a MySQL database on a server that I'm renting through godaddy. Everything's fine, but I have a simple yet debatable question: My client does not want to host the database online (they're scared of security and think anual fees are a pain). They want a local database, nevertheless, they do not own a server where I could deploy a database instance. I've thought of some very ugly solutions, such as creating the database using Microsft Access and sharing the database on a network folder, but I don't find this appealing at all. So, does anyone have any recommendations? How could I deploy a local database (MySql, Sql Server) on a small office without an actual server?

Comment: So SQLite should be your choice for simple.

Comment: You can run MySQL off a USB stick if you want to, but we just use an ancient PC in the corner of the room.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with YB up to the point of suggesting that a database should reside on NAS. There are horrible complications and performance issues with such an approach (and, BTW, doing this with MSAccess is even worse).

I'm struggling to imagine what kind of pay of you are on when your client can afford a custom application but can't afford a dedicated server - it's possible to get a basic PC with software RAID1 for under 200GBP (290 USD). Whether you want to add the expense of a MSWindows licence is optional - MySQL will run just as well (better?) on a free OS.

Comment: NAS can be the only box in the office running 24/7, likely to have UPS and backup. We do not know the workload requirements for the DB, so the performance might not be the issue. There are plenty of discussions "DB on NAS" on the Internet to consider pros and contras. Any modern NAS have better specs then the best database server 20 years ago and those were fine. :-)

Comment: @YB: specs of a NAS have nothing to do with managing concurrency which is where most of the problems arise. And, just like the server function, UPS/Backup is not restricted to a NAS.

Answer (score 0):

Server is a function, not an entity. Any client PC can double as a server. Pick the one that would use the database the most and install MySQL server there. NAS can serve DB. Old and unwanted laptop can serve DB and it's battery might work as a UPS for the whole couple of minutes of life left in it.

I personally would install MySQL on every user PC, nominate one as the live server and use all the others as replication / backup.